# I have a schengen visa can I enter to london

Tags: uk, schengen, pakistan

I have a schengen short stay  visa can I enter to london
I have examine pte acedemic test  in london

Comment: Nope you can't. You need a British Visa for that.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can’t. The UK is (at least for now) a member of the EU but it is not part of the Schengen area. You need a UK visitor visa https://www.gov.uk/apply-uk-visa